# is it possible to batch-authorize a Drive folder and subfolders for access by an Android app?

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

Here's the use case... I've got an Android app. I'd like my users to organize some data files on their Google Drive into a specific directory structure

```
My Drive/
  appName/
    folderA/
      fileA1
      fileA2
      ...
      fileAN
    folderB/
      fileB1
      fileB2
      ...
      fileBN
```

I'd also like to let my users share their configurations with each other.

```
My Drive/      # User1's drive
  appName/
    folderA/
      fileA1
      fileA2
      ...
      fileAN
    folderB/
      fileB1
      fileB2
      ...
      fileBN

    folderC/    # User2's MyDrive/appName/folderC, which they shared with User1
      fileC1
      fileC2
      ...
      fileCN
```

These folders will potentially have hundreds of files in them.

My app never needs to delete/rename/create the files. It *only* needs to traverse the directory structure and read the content of the files.

I want the users to manage their data files using semantics they're already familiar with -- create/manage/edit the file contents using the usual Google Drive web application.

From what I've started reading... It seems like the drive.file scope is going to cause problems with the workflow I had planned. From the docs "This means that only files which a user has opened or created with your application can be matched by a query."

What are my options for letting my users indicate "this Android app has read-only access to files under 'My Drive/appName'"?

Is the Google Drive Android API a bad fit for my use case? Should I just focus on the Google Drive REST API instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will have better luck with the Google Drive JAVA API. On Android Drive api page (https://developers.google.com/drive/android/queries), it is said that:

> Note: The Android Drive API only works with the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file scope. This means that only files which a user has opened or created with your application can be matched by a query.

You can follow the guide in the Google Drive Java API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/java). It takes quite a bit of modifications to make it works on Android. To give you a head start, here is a working code for how to request the Google Drive service. You can change the scope to be READONLY

```
// Retrieve drive service
    com.google.api.services.drive.Drive service = null;
    synchronized (signInLock) {
        try {
            if (googleSignInAccount == null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Wait for google sign in");
                signInLock.wait();
            }
            GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential
                    .usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                    .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
                    .setSelectedAccountName(googleSignInAccount.getEmail());
            service = new com.google.api.services.drive.Drive.Builder(
                    AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), credential)
                    .setApplicationName(Version.APP_NAME)
                    .build();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "InterruptedException " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error while getting drive service " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }
    }
    if (service == null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Drive service is null");
        return;
    }
```

And this is how you get the googleSignInAccount

```
    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions
            .DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(Drive.API)  // Google Drive Android API
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso) // Google Sign-in Api
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this) // ConnectionCallbacks
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this) // OnConnectionFailedListener
            .build();

private void googleSilentSignIn() {
    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> pendingResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(
            mGoogleApiClient);
    if (pendingResult.isDone()) {
        // There's immediate result available.
        handleSignInResult(pendingResult.get());
    } else {
        // There's no immediate result ready, waits for the async callback.
        pendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult result) {
                handleSignInResult(result);
            }
        });
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult: " + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        googleSignInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        synchronized (signInLock) {
            signInLock.notify();
        }
    }
}
```